# Kendoui Menu add using JSON

Tags: menu, kendo-ui

I'm trying to dynamically add a sub menu item with id property, using JSON.  Initially, the menu is created using MVC like this:

```
children.Add().Text("Incoming")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "AddDevice-20" }).Enabled(false);
```

and I'm able to grab the "id" out when selected.

However, on the client side I'm adding the sub menu via JavaScript like this:

```
function KendoMenuAdd(menuName, menuId, parentIndex) {
        var menuData = $("#Menu").data("kendoMenu");
        var menuItemToAdd = [{ text: menuName, id: menuId }];
        var parent = $("#Menu").children("li").eq(parentIndex);
        menuData.append(menuItemToAdd, parent);

    }
```

The submenu is added successfully but the "id" is not.  When I debug, the id is "Menu_mn_active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` is not added because it means nothing for Kendo Menu. There is no option when you define a Menu that is `id`.

So, why in the first case you have that id? Simple because you said `HtmlAttributes(new { id = "AddDevice-20" })` which means that it is an HTML attribute while `Text("Incoming")` defines a Kendo Menu attribute. It would be different if you have had something like:

```
children.Add()
        .Text("Incoming")
        .Id("AddDevice-20")
        .Enabled(false);
```

Defining an HTML attribute is like saying:

```
<li id="AddDevice-20">Incoming</li>
```

The difference is that the `id` becomes an attribute of `li`.

**EDIT** If you certainly need an `id`, what you might do is defining for using a template that contains an element with an `id`. Something like:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/kendo-ui">
    <span id="${id}" class='ob-menu-item'>${text}</span>
</script>
```

Where I create a `span` element which `id` is whatever you want. The reason for using the CSS class `ob-menu-item` is explained a little bellow.

Then the function for creating the new menu entry is:

```
function KendoMenuAdd(menuName, menuId, parentIndex) {
    var template = kendo.template($("#my-template").html());
    var menuData = $("#Menu").data("kendoMenu");
    menuData.insertAfter({ text: template({ text: menuName, id: menuId}), 
                           encoded: false }, parentIndex);
}
```

The *trick* is in setting the value `text` to the `HTML` produced by using the template and as `encoded` to `false` to let Kendo UI know that is not text but HTML.

If in the `select` method you need to retrieve the `id`, now is as simple as:

```
select : function (e) {
    alert("the id is:" + $(".ob-menu-item", e.item).attr("id"));
}
```

Where I use the CSS class `ob-menu-item` for finding the child under the menu item that contains the `id`.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6KVRh/

The advantage of this solution is that you do not manipulate HTML elements so you make your self more independent of whatever Kendo UI decides to change. If you try to mimic the clases and elements that Kendo UI uses, any change in the code that they generate will break your site. A method that they publish in the documentation is like a contract that they should not break or all their clients will be updset. If you use their methods, then you should be safe.

Comment: There is no property Id that was why I used the HtmlAttributes, which served my purpose. Regardless, the question is "how can I add ID using the JSON method in function KendoMenuAdd().

Comment: OnaBai, I solved my own problem.  I decided to use HTML directly like this: $("#PSMenuDevice ul").append("<li class=\"k-item k-state-enabled k-state-default\" id=\"MenuId-10\" role=\"menuitem\"><span class=\"k-link\">Menu Text</span></li>").